# Check if text is overflow outside text element of svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

If we use character from other languages like Danish then characters accent gets out of the text box, is there a way to detect if text is overflowing height wise?

My element is wrapped inside g element with clip path.
This is required output
[image]

But when we use clip path we don't get if text is overflowing outside clip path
[image]

[image]

Comment: SVG doesn't have text boxes so it can't overflow something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand your point. I edited my question, my element is wrapped inside g element with clip path,

Comment: call getBBox on the text element and see if it is clipped i.e. it goes outside the clip-path bounds.

Comment: @Tushar Kotlapure Add the specific code causing the problem and you will surely get a specific answer that solves your problem

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  I have added example

Comment: @TusharKotlapure Please add a code and not a picture